# Understanding an if statement in assembly

Tags: disassembly, assembly, c, gdb

I have written two simple C programs (one with an `if` and one without).  Looking at the assembly differences there are a few lines that I can't manage to explain and was hoping to get some assistance.  The `if` based C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        char buffer[256];
        if(sizeof(buffer) >= sizeof(argv[1])) {
                strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
       }
       return 0;
}
```

The assembly for this is:

```
#   0x4005d6 <main>         push   rbp
#   0x4005d7 <main+1>       mov    rbp,rsp
#   0x4005da <main+4>       sub    rsp,0x120
#   0x4005e1 <main+11>      mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x114],edi
#   0x4005e7 <main+17>      mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x120],rsi
#   0x4005ee <main+24>      mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28

    0x4005f7 <main+33>      mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
    0x4005fb <main+37>      xor    eax,eax
    0x4005fd <main+39>      mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x120]

#   0x400604 <main+46>      add    rax,0x8
#   0x400608 <main+50>      mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rax]
#   0x40060b <main+53>      lea    rax,[rbp-0x110]
#   0x400612 <main+60>      mov    rsi,rdx
#   0x400615 <main+63>      mov    rdi,rax
#   0x400618 <main+66>      call   0x400490 <strcpy@plt>
#   0x40061d <main+71>      lea    rax,[rbp-0x110]
#   0x400624 <main+78>      mov    rdi,rax
#   0x400627 <main+81>      call   0x4004a0 <puts@plt>
#   0x40062c <main+86>      mov    eax,0x0

    0x400631 <main+91>       mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
    0x400635 <main+95>       xor    rcx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
    0x40063e <main+104>      je     0x400645 <main+111>
    0x400640 <main+106>      call   0x4004b0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>

#   0x400645 <main+111>     leave
#   0x400646 <main+112>     ret
```

The parts of the assembly with `#` are exactly the same as the code without the if statement (I included it for ease and readability).  The lines that have me confused are line `main+91` through `main+106`.

I don't get why an if statement would somehow add these bits and was hoping for a little insight.

Answer (score 3):

The code you are referring to is a check for `argv[1]` being initialized most likely.

The main problem here is that you are actually comparing two static numbers, i.e. `sizeof(argv[1])` is going to ALWAYS be the same (and also smaller than 256), no matter what the `argv[1]` is. The compiler knows this, thus omits the whole 'if' statement. It should also segfault / have undefined behavior if there is no `argv[1]`. Needless to say, you can easily buffer overflow here..

What you really wanted to do is this:

```
...   
if(sizeof(buffer) > strlen(argv[1])){    
... 
}
...
```

Reason for '`>`' and not '`>=`' is that the null terminated string needs the null terminator, which is not accounted for when calculating the `strlen()` (or add one).

Answer (score 3):

Just to add on Sigtran answer, part of the assembly code you are pinpointing is coming from the stack-smashing protection. It seems that you have it enabled by default on your system.

Try to recompile your code with the option: `-fno-stack-protector` and look at the assembly again. It should clean out most of these lines that you do not understand (if not all).

**PS**: If you want a more detailed answer about what does this code, feel free to add a comment to my answer and I will detail these lines in my answer.